# Progress bar not working using jquery and html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have implemented a progress bar on my multi-step form. But after submitting form progress bar is not showing as page reload.
Find my code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myBtn').click(function(){
        animateProgressBar(90);
 //mybtn is the button id of submit button in form   
    
    
    });
function animateProgressBar(percentageCompleted)
{

$('#innerDiv').animate({
   
'width':(1000*percentageCompleted)/100 


},1000);
$({counter: 1}).animate({counter:percentageCompleted},{duration:1000,
step:function()
{
    $('#innerDiv').text(Math.ceil(this.counter)+'%');
}

})
}

});
```

```html
 <div id="outerDiv" style="background-color:white; height:20px; width:1000px; padding:5px;">
        <div id="innerDiv" style="background-color:#138581; height:19px; width:0px; color:white; text-align:center;"> </div></div>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  If submitting the form reloads the page (which is expected for plain HTML forms) then what is the progress bar meant to accomplish?  The page is already reloaded and the operation is complete.  If the progress bar was shown before reloading the page, then is it just reloading fast enough that you don't see it?  In which case, what's the issue?  Did you perhaps want to submit the form via AJAX instead and show a progress bar (or loading indicator of some sort) while it processes?

Comment: its a multi-step form...so need to show progress on each submit

Comment: Okay, but... If submitting the form reloads the page (which is expected for plain HTML forms) then what is the progress bar meant to accomplish? The page is already reloaded and the operation is complete. If the progress bar was shown before reloading the page, then is it just reloading fast enough that you don't see it? In which case, what's the issue? Did you perhaps want to submit the form via AJAX instead and show a progress bar (or loading indicator of some sort) while it processes?

Comment: Is there any way that after submission of one form progress bar display 30%(let's say) and then move to next section of form with progress bar displaying the same percentage.

Comment: There's a way to do just about anything, sure.  It depends on how you've built these forms and how the user navigates through them.  For example, if each form is another page then why not simply have a static "progress bar" shown on each page?  Or if the forms are all on the same page and are dynamically shown/hidden via server-side code, then why not show/hide a static progress bar using the same logic?  Currently the problem you appear to be describing is that you're trying to show something and then immediately reload the page.  So of course whatever was shown is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to persist the progress between page reloads.

Use `window.localStorage.setItem('progress', 90);` to set the progress of the current step in your form.

User `window.localStorage.getItem('progress')` to retrieve the progress you set previously.

So you would set the current progress in the localStorage, and on each refresh you retrieve it and show it again.